# Adding json array in a json object in java

Tags: java, json

I am struggling to fit in a jsonArray inside a json object (through java code).. please help me out.

My Input JsonObject is :

```
{ 
   "products":{  
      "productId":"712161780324",
      "imageURL":"http:example.com/imageResource.jpg",
      "internalItemCode":"N08792 8W"
      }
}
```

I will have to read "imageURL" property from this JSONObject and append its variants to the same json object (image variants will be in SortedSet data structure).

**Sample O/P 1 :**

```
{  
   "products":{  
      "productId":"712161780324",
      "imageURL":"http:example.com/imageResource.jpg",
      "internalItemCode":"N08792 8W",
      "variants":[  
         "http:example.com/imageResource_variant1.jpg",
         "http:example.com/imageResource_variant2.jpg"
      ]
   }
}
```

Sample O/P 2 :

```
{  
   "products":{  
      "productId":"712161780324",
      "imageURL":"http:example.com/imageResource.jpg",
      "internalItemCode":"N08792 8W",
      "variants":[ 
            { 
             "url" : "http:example.com/imageResource_variant1.jpg"
            },
           {
            "url" : "http:example.com/imageResource_variant2.jpg"
           }
      ]
   }
}
```

The logic i tried to get sample output 2 is some what like below,

```
// productDetail is the give input JSONObject
    JSONObject product = productDetail.optJSONObject("products");
    SortedSet<String> imageUrls = new TreeSet<>(); 
    imageUrls.add("http:example.com/imageResource_variant1.jpg"); 
    imageUrls.add("http:example.com/imageResource_variant2.jpg"); 
    Iterator<String> itr = imageUrls.iterator();
    JSONArray imageUrlsArray = new JSONArray();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        JSONObject imageUrlObj = new JSONObject();
        imageUrlObj.put("url", itr.next());
        imageUrlsArray.put(imageUrlObj);
        }
    product.append("variants", imageUrlsArray);
```

When i tried to print the productDetail JSON object after executing above logic

System.out.println(productDetail.toString());

I observed the following output :

```
{  
   "products":{  
      "productId":"712161780324",
      "imageURL":"http:example.com/imageResource.jpg",
      "internalItemCode":"N08792 8W",
      "variants":[
           [ 
            { 
             "url" : "http:example.com/imageResource_variant1.jpg"
            },
           {
            "url" : "http:example.com/imageResource_variant2.jpg"
           }
      ]
     ]
   }
}
```

If you notice, It's coming up like Array of arrays (extra [ ] for "variants"), 
Please help me in understanding Where my logic is going wrong.

And also, Please help me getting the First sample out put.

Appreciate quick response..

Thanks,
Rohit.

Answer (score 0):

First sample can be archivable as simple as this:

```
    JSONObject product = productDetail.optJSONObject("products");
    JSONArray imageUrlsArray = new JSONArray();
    imageUrlsArray.put(0, "http:example.com/imageResource_variant1.jpg");
    imageUrlsArray.put(1, "http:example.com/imageResource_variant2.jpg");
    product.append("variants", imageUrlsArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `put` instead of `append`:

```
 JSONObject product = productDetail.optJSONObject("products");
 SortedSet<String> imageUrls = new TreeSet<>(); 
 imageUrls.add("http:example.com/imageResource_variant1.jpg"); 
 imageUrls.add("http:example.com/imageResource_variant2.jpg"); 
 Iterator<String> itr = imageUrls.iterator();
 JSONArray imageUrlsArray = new JSONArray();
 while (itr.hasNext()) {
     JSONObject imageUrlObj = new JSONObject();
     imageUrlObj.put("url", itr.next());
     imageUrlsArray.put(imageUrlObj);
     }
-product.append("variants", imageUrlsArray);
+product.put("variants", imageUrlsArray);
```

From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/maf240/mobile/api-ref/oracle/adfmf/json/JSONObject.html#append-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-):

> Append values to the array under a key. If the key does not exist in the JSONObject, then the key is put in the JSONObject with its value being a JSONArray containing the value parameter. If the key was already associated with a JSONArray, then the value parameter is appended to it.